# Why does the Jetpack Compose Material 3 Card composable require a ColumnScope for its content?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm working with `Jetpack Compose` and recently noticed that the `Card` composable from the `androidx.compose.material3` package requires its content to be provided within a `ColumnScope.` Specifically, the content parameter of the Card function expects a lambda of type `@Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit`.

Why is the `ColumnScope` necessary in this context? What advantages or functionalities does it provide when using the `Card` component?

I've tried to understand its purpose from the official documentation, but I couldn't find a clear explanation. Any insights or clarifications would be greatly appreciated!

```
package androidx.compose.material3
@Composable
fun Card(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    shape: Shape = CardDefaults.shape,
    colors: CardColors = CardDefaults.cardColors(),
    elevation: CardElevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(),
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier,
        shape = shape,
        color = colors.containerColor(enabled = true).value,
        contentColor = colors.contentColor(enabled = true).value,
        tonalElevation = elevation.tonalElevation(enabled = true, interactionSource =         null).value,
        shadowElevation = elevation.shadowElevation(enabled = true, interactionSource     = null).value,
        border = border,
    ) {
        Column(content = content)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think why ```Card``` has default ```ColumnScope``` it's because of you can easily align your content vertically and if you want to change you can add ```Box``` or ```Other Composable``` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the [Material3 Design Guidelines for the Card](https://m3.material.io/components/cards/guidelines), you'll find the following line on the very top of the *Usage* section:

> Elements like text and images should be placed on cards in a way that clearly indicates hierarchy.

This strongly points to hierarchical layout, which usually is tied to a vertical direction of placing children.

By requiring a `ColumnScope` for the content of the `Card`, it is easier to provide `Card` content that adheres to the Design Guidelines. 
 Android developers thus are encouraged to follow the Design Guidelines, and save some time while doing so, as they directly can use all `Modifier`s on the content that usually only would be available for Composables that are children of a `Column`. For example, you can directly use [`Modifier.align`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).align(androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal)) to horizontally position the items.

To me, it seems like this is rather for convenience and to encourage following the guidelines. This is my perspective on this, although there might not be a definitive answer.